# I can't reach the IIS Virtual directory, what could be the cause of the error?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

A virtual directory has been opened before and the pictures are taken from there by accessing the link, so I wrote a new project and I wanted to shoot it the same way, but the problem is that the link of the pictures is coming, but the pictures are not coming, why can this be?

```
var logo = @Model.Parametre.Data.Parametre.RESIMPATH.Replace("MODEL", 
       "LOGO") + @Model.Parametre.Data.Parametre.RESIM;
var image = @Model.Parametre.Data.Parametre.RESIMPATH + urun.RESIMX;
                        <div class="product-layout product-grid col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 first-item">
                            <div class="product-block product-thumb">
                                <div class="product-block-inner">
                                    <div class="image" style="height: 300px">
                                        <a asp-area="B2B" asp-controller="UrunMamul" asp-action="ProductDetail" asp-route-id=@urun.ID asp-route-aciklama=@SeoHelper.FriendlyURLTitle(urun.ACIKLAMA2.ToLower())>
                                            <img src="@image" onerror="this.onerror = null; this.src ='@logo';" title="@SeoHelper.FriendlyURLTitle(urun.ACIKLAMA2.ToLower())" alt="@SeoHelper.FriendlyURLTitle(urun.ACIKLAMA2.ToLower())" style="width: auto; max-height: 300px; max-width: 100%;" class="img-responsive reg-image" id="zoom_01" asp-append-version="true">
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
```

here the onerror drops because the codes can't find the path and it doesn't bring the logo

Comment: How was the virtual directory created? Was it also created for the new project?

Comment: they have already created. I just rewrote the project. do i have to create it from scratch